# About Blender logo in my Youtube video

Tags: licensing

I am making videos on Youtube about products I made by Blender. I don't know that is it ok if I put the Blender logo on my video's cover image. Is it copyright?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and copyright

Comment: see https://www.blender.org/about/logo/

Answer (score 4):

This is not a question about using Blender, licensing and legal matters are considered off topic here, we are not lawyers and cannot be liable for answers given here.

Since there is an official document about it online in the [Blender official website](https://www.blender.org/about/logo/), where you can find the recommended Blender logo usage guidelines, I will just quote it verbatim.

> ## Blender logo usage guidelines
>
> Blender is a registered trademark (®) of the Blender Foundation in EU
> and USA. The Blender logo itself is a property of the Blender
> Foundation. The logo and the brand name “Blender” are not part of the
> GNU GPL, and can only be used commercially by the Blender Foundation
> on products, websites, and publications.
>
> Under the following conditions, third parties may use the Blender logo
> as well:
>
> 1. The logo can only be used to point to the product Blender. When used with a link on a web page, it should point to the URL
>    blender.org.
> 2. You will visualize and promote your own branding more prominent than you use the Blender logo. The Blender logo only can be used as a
>    secondary brand, which means it has to be clear for an average viewer
>    that this is not an official Blender or Blender Foundation website,
>    publication or product.
> 3. You can use the Blender logo on promotion products, such as T-shirts or caps or trade show booths, provided it is a secondary
>    brand as described in point 2.
> 4. The logo is used unaltered, without fancy enhancements, in original colors, original typography, and always complete (logo + text
>    blender).
> 5. In case you use the logo on products you sell commercially, you always have to contact us with a picture of how it will be used, and
>    ask for explicit permission.
>
> If you have further questions or doubts, do not hesitate to contact
> us.

In short you can use it as long as you don't make it look like your product is made by the Blender Foundation, nor that you are somehow endorsed by or officially associated with it.

Comment: Do note that starting an answer with a paragraph explaining why it's off-topic is very ambiguous. Vote to close or flag a question for migration if you believe it's a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Your first paragraph explains exactly why you shouldn't have answered.

Comment: Since there is an official document about it it seemed like a safe-ish answer to just quote it